# WMI Query to identify virtual machines under Server 2012 R2

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, wmi

We need to identify VMs to filter GPOs. There is an old trick to query the Win32_ComputerSystem for Manufacturer being VMware or something *virtual*. This works for my Server 2008 R2 VMs, but all Server 2012 R2 VMs have this output, if I query using PowerShell:

```
PS C:\> gwmi Win32_ComputerSystem | fl Manufacturer, Model

Manufacturer : HP 
Model        : ProLiant DL380 Gen9
```

Any Idea why my VMs are ProLiant Servers?

Comment: Works on my 2012R2 VM: `Manufacturer : VMware, Inc. Model : VMware Virtual Platform`. Which hypervisor and version? Anything special about this particular VM?

Answer (score 2):

See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15485601/how-to-check-my-windows-server-is-virtual-machine-or-physical-machine

Consider trying
***gwmi win32_baseboard***.  Results below are using Windows as the hypervisor - physical hardware unknown.

```
Manufacturer : Microsoft Corporation
Model        : 
Name         : Base Board
SerialNumber : <some unique identifiers - snipped>
SKU          : 
Product      : Virtual Machine
```

For what it's worth, on my vanilla Server 2012R2 machine, **gwmi win32_computersystem**:

```
Manufacturer        : Microsoft Corporation
Model               : Virtual Machine
```

It sounds as if you may be using a hypervisor other than Windows or a management solution/product/agent from HP that may be managing your VMs and changing the value.

Comment: Thanks for your input; using win32_baseboard, my W2k12 server tells me he's a "440BX Desktop Reference Platform" in the "Product" column. I think this maybe a OS image / HP Software issue.